# Plugins cloud_firestore and firebase_auth are preventing syncing with android Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i am trying to implement the firebase database in my project in order to save data later but every time i add

cloud_firestore:
firebase_auth:

to my pubspec.yaml file no matter what version i get all sorts of errors

e.g. :

```
Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.'
```

(which leads me to a new question. Why does the error message call it firbase_auth_WEB. I mean where does the word "web" come from and why)

```
    Note: C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.15.5+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 95560 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:432)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:242)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:57)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)``
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: null
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.1.62.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Y.a(SourceFile:78)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 95560 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.error(SourceFile:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P.a(SourceFile:740)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$h.a(SourceFile:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:14)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(SourceFile:25)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Y.a(SourceFile:36)
    ... 38 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
    To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
    To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Does anywone know how to solve this ?

And are there discord servers for showing fellow coders said problems?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file

means that you need to [raise your minSdkVersion to at least 21 or otherwise enable MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex). This is also explained in the [Firebase Android installation documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android#enabling-multidex).

If the problem still occur, please share a snippet of your pubspec.yaml that contains your declaration of the dependencies.